# 人間 vs 人 to refer to an individual?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Some context:
Person A and Person B both went through a trying situation dealing with Person C, someone that Person A has known for many years. They are now talking about how awful it was. Person A then thinks this:

> [俺]{おれ}に[比]{くら}べて[汚染]{おせん}[度]{ど}１０[年分]{ねんぶん}も[少]{すく}ないなんて、なんて[幸]{しあわ}せな[人間]{にんげん}だ。

which as far as I understand is something along the lines of: Person B has suffered 10 years less than I have. How lucky Person B is.

I was pretty surprised 人間 was the choice of word here. I would have expected 人 instead because in my experience 人間  refers to humanity or a type of person. Is this something that's done frequently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this example sentence is natural.

人間【にんげん】 can be used, as well as 人【ひと】, when one shows their hatred against someone, or when one wants to keep a distance from someone.

> 1. 私はあの人が好きです。: OK
> 2. 私はあの人が嫌いです。: OK
> 3. 私はあの人間が好きです。: **Weird**
> 4. 私はあの人間が嫌いです。: **OK**

To me, #4 sounds even more hostile than #2.

Likewise, 「彼はそういう人です。(That's how he is.)」 can be used both positively or negatively, but 「彼はそういう人間です。」 is usually negative.

In the sentence in question, なんて幸せな人だ is also OK, but なんて幸せな人間だ sounds like Person A displays a somewhat unfriendly attitude to Person B.

I can't explain the logic behind this, but perhaps the speaker is keeping a distance from the subject by using 人間, the word that does not sound very friendly.

Comment: Well I think the person that Person A is saying is 幸せな is Person B. I don't think there would be a reason to be unfriendly there. The rest of this seems to make quite a bit of sense though.

Comment: @Ringil Thanks, my mistake. If A and B are close friends, and A said this in front of B, then I think A said this probably half-jokingly/sarcastically.

Comment: As I said in my question, A _thinks_ this. I would agree with you if he had spoken that, but since A and B are close friends it seems somewhat confusing to _think_ that.

Comment: Sorry, then perhaps A *thought* this out of strong jealousy against B? Judging from this sentence alone, I don't think A is celebrating B's luck at heart, anyway.

Comment: Or maybe A was just trying to be thinking objectively. Addressing someone out loud in front of you as 人間 is generally rude, but it may be acceptable in a monologue.

Comment: Can you use 人間 to talk about yourself in a negative way?

Comment: @Chris Yes, for example, something like 私は料理ができない人間/人です.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure, but I guess that's only the limitation of the writer's vocabulary.

I would write the said phrase as 俺に比べて汚染度１０年分も少ないなんて、なんて幸せな奴だ。

Comment: Limited vocabulary? Sorry, but that's nonsense. Do you think _anyone_ (including learners and native speakers) would know 人間 and not 人? And 奴 is almost always used simply as an informal way of saying 人.

Comment: I've seen 人間　used that way multiple times by native speakers.

Comment: @Earthliŋ: What are you talking about? Do you really think that I am asserting that anyone (including learners and native speakers) would know 人間 and not 人? I have no idea why you reached that conclusion. Do please read again what I have written!  The original writer uses 俺 for addressing himself. Then 奴 would be more appropriate to address somebody else than 人間, right?

Comment: The question asked "why choose 人間 over 人" and you answered "limitation of the writer's vocabulary".

Comment: @Earthliŋ: You should recall that Ringil asked "Is this something that's done frequently?"

Comment: I still don't think "limitation of the writer's vocabulary" is relevant here at all.

Comment: @Earthliŋ: I do think "limitation of the writer's vocabulary" is relevant here. The original writer should have chosen more appropriate word corresponding to  俺. If he had chosen 奴, Ringil might not have felt puzzled.

Comment: I highly doubt writer vocabulary limitations are at play here...

Comment: @Ringil: Of course it's just my guess, but I am sceptical about the literacy of the original writer.